# C# WinApi KeyEven is always true after I let go of the key

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm working on a small project.
I check if space is pressed but when it is pressed it never stops.
This is my code:

```
            bool bunnyJump = Program.ConfigUtils.GetValue<bool>("Bunny Jump");
        if (bunnyJump)
        {
            if (WinAPI.GetKeyState((int)Keys.Space) != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Space");
            }
        }
```

I only want to do `Console.WriteLine("Space");` when SpaceBar is held down.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong. It should be `if (WinAPI.GetKeyState((int)Keys.Space) < 0)` instead. See [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```cs
bool pressed = false;
/*stuff*/
void Update()
{
    /*stuff*/
    if (bunnyJump)
        if (!pressed && WinApi.GetKeyState((int)Keys.Space) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Space");
            pressed = true;
        }
        else if (pressed && WinApi.GetKeyState((int)Keys.Space) == 0)
            pressed = false;
    /*stuff*/
}
```

Create a global boolean that starts off being false. If the space key is held and it is false, then output the message and set it to true. Otherwise, if the space key isn't held and it is true, set it to false.